# How to create a Tree structure in HTML using a n level nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, web-component

I am trying to achieve a scalable solution for creating a tree structure with n level nesting of Objects within Objects. Baiscally, I want to create a Web Component which can be used as a Tree component when it is fed a with nested JSON structure.

E.g. Sample JSON is what I am showing below:

```
this._sData = {
        "column_definition": {
            "0": {
                "property": "display_key",
                "title": "Country"
            },
            "1": {
                "property": "text",
                "title": ""
            }
        },
        "root": {
            "0": {
                "0": {
                    "0": {
                        "display_key": "8",
                        "text": "Belgium",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000008"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "display_key": "18",
                        "text": "Czech Republic",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000018"
                    },
                    "10": {
                        "display_key": "37",
                        "text": "Luxembourg",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000037"
                    },
                    "11": {
                        "display_key": "42",
                        "text": "Netherlands",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000042"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "display_key": "19",
                        "text": "Denmark",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000019"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "display_key": "23",
                        "text": "England",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000023"
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "display_key": "24",
                        "text": "Finland",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000024"
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "display_key": "25",
                        "text": "France",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000025"
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "display_key": "26",
                        "text": "Germany",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000026"
                    },
                    "7": {
                        "display_key": "27",
                        "text": "Greece",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000027"
                    },
                    "8": {
                        "display_key": "28",
                        "text": "Hungary",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000028"
                    },
                    "9": {
                        "display_key": "31",
                        "text": "Ireland",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000031"
                    },
                    "display_key": "EUROPE",
                    "state": "E",
                    "text": "EUROPE",
                    "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/EUROPE"
                },
                "1": {
                    "0": {
                        "display_key": "13",
                        "text": "Canada",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000013"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "display_key": "67",
                        "text": "USA",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000067"
                    },
                    "display_key": "NORTH_AMERICA",
                    "state": "E",
                    "text": "NORTH_AMERICA",
                    "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/NORTH_AMERICA"
                },
                "2": {
                    "0": {
                        "display_key": "3",
                        "text": "Australia",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000003"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "display_key": "6",
                        "text": "Bangladesh",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000006"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "display_key": "15",
                        "text": "China",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000015"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "display_key": "30",
                        "text": "Indonesia",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000030"
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "display_key": "35",
                        "text": "Japan",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000035"
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "display_key": "38",
                        "text": "Malaysia",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000038"
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "display_key": "41",
                        "text": "Nepal",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000041"
                    },
                    "7": {
                        "display_key": "50",
                        "text": "Philippines",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000050"
                    },
                    "8": {
                        "display_key": "58",
                        "text": "Singapore",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000058"
                    },
                    "9": {
                        "display_key": "63",
                        "text": "Thailand",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000063"
                    },
                    "display_key": "ASIA_PAC",
                    "state": "E",
                    "text": "ASIA_PAC",
                    "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/ASIA_PAC"
                },
                "3": {
                    "0": {
                        "display_key": "36",
                        "text": "Kenya",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000036"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "display_key": "47",
                        "text": "Pakistan",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000047"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "display_key": "56",
                        "text": "Saudi Arabia",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000056"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "display_key": "59",
                        "text": "South Africa",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000059"
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "display_key": "64",
                        "text": "Turkey",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000064"
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "display_key": "66",
                        "text": "United Arab Emirates",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000066"
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "display_key": "71",
                        "text": "Zimbabwe",
                        "value": "000000000000000000000000000071"
                    },
                    "display_key": "MIDDLE_EAST",
                    "state": "E",
                    "text": "MIDDLE_EAST",
                    "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/MIDDLE_EAST"
                },
                "display_key": "WORLD",
                "state": "E",
                "text": "WORLD",
                "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/WORLD"
            },
            "36": {
                "0": {
                    "value": "Loading"
                },
                "display_key": "REST_H",
                "state": "C",
                "text": "Not Assigned Country (s)",
                "value": "HIERARCHY_NODE/1HIER_REST/REST_H"
            },
            "value": "root"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following function to iterate and map the nested objects:

```
let flattenObject = (obj) => {
    let result = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(item => {
        if(typeof(obj[item]) == 'object'){
            Object.keys(obj[item]).forEach(nestedItem => {
                if(typeof(obj[nestedItem]) == 'object'){
                    flattenObject(obj[nestedItem]);
                }
                else{
                   result = Object.assign({}, obj[item]);
                }
            })
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

I expect the output to be something like this when I parsing the JSON and rendering in the HTML:

```
    <ul>World
    <li><ul>Europe
    <li>Czech Republic</li>
    <li>Belgium</li>
    <li>United Kingdom</li></ul>
    <ul>Asia
    <li>China</li>
    <li>India</li>
    ...etc.
   </ul>
    <ul>Rest of World
    <li>Honduras</li>
    ...etc.
```

Also nexting of objects can be of n-levels so I want a generic solution.

Comment: why not use an array instead of an object with index like keys?

Comment: Have you looked at D3.js?  They have pretty interesting force-directed graphs that can be used for parent-child data of all types.

Comment: `Sample JSON` - seems to be invalid JSON

Answer (score 2):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function getList(object) {
    return Object.values(object).reduce((ul, v) => {
        if (!v || typeof v !== 'object') return ul;
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v.text));
        li.appendChild(getList(v));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        return ul;
    }, document.createElement('ul'));
}

var data = { column_definition: { "0": { property: "display_key", title: "Country" }, "1": { property: "text", title: "" } }, root: { "0": { "0": { "0": { display_key: "8", text: "Belgium", value: "000000000000000000000000000008" }, "1": { display_key: "18", text: "Czech Republic", value: "000000000000000000000000000018" }, "2": { display_key: "19", text: "Denmark", value: "000000000000000000000000000019" }, "3": { display_key: "23", text: "England", value: "000000000000000000000000000023" }, "4": { display_key: "24", text: "Finland", value: "000000000000000000000000000024" }, "5": { display_key: "25", text: "France", value: "000000000000000000000000000025" }, "6": { display_key: "26", text: "Germany", value: "000000000000000000000000000026" }, "7": { display_key: "27", text: "Greece", value: "000000000000000000000000000027" }, "8": { display_key: "28", text: "Hungary", value: "000000000000000000000000000028" }, "9": { display_key: "31", text: "Ireland", value: "000000000000000000000000000031" }, "10": { display_key: "37", text: "Luxembourg", value: "000000000000000000000000000037" }, "11": { display_key: "42", text: "Netherlands", value: "000000000000000000000000000042" }, display_key: "EUROPE", state: "E", text: "EUROPE", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/EUROPE" }, "1": { "0": { display_key: "13", text: "Canada", value: "000000000000000000000000000013" }, "1": { display_key: "67", text: "USA", value: "000000000000000000000000000067" }, display_key: "NORTH_AMERICA", state: "E", text: "NORTH_AMERICA", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/NORTH_AMERICA" }, "2": { "0": { display_key: "3", text: "Australia", value: "000000000000000000000000000003" }, "1": { display_key: "6", text: "Bangladesh", value: "000000000000000000000000000006" }, "2": { display_key: "15", text: "China", value: "000000000000000000000000000015" }, "3": { display_key: "30", text: "Indonesia", value: "000000000000000000000000000030" }, "4": { display_key: "35", text: "Japan", value: "000000000000000000000000000035" }, "5": { display_key: "38", text: "Malaysia", value: "000000000000000000000000000038" }, "6": { display_key: "41", text: "Nepal", value: "000000000000000000000000000041" }, "7": { display_key: "50", text: "Philippines", value: "000000000000000000000000000050" }, "8": { display_key: "58", text: "Singapore", value: "000000000000000000000000000058" }, "9": { display_key: "63", text: "Thailand", value: "000000000000000000000000000063" }, display_key: "ASIA_PAC", state: "E", text: "ASIA_PAC", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/ASIA_PAC" }, "3": { "0": { display_key: "36", text: "Kenya", value: "000000000000000000000000000036" }, "1": { display_key: "47", text: "Pakistan", value: "000000000000000000000000000047" }, "2": { display_key: "56", text: "Saudi Arabia", value: "000000000000000000000000000056" }, "3": { display_key: "59", text: "South Africa", value: "000000000000000000000000000059" }, "4": { display_key: "64", text: "Turkey", value: "000000000000000000000000000064" }, "5": { display_key: "66", text: "United Arab Emirates", value: "000000000000000000000000000066" }, "6": { display_key: "71", text: "Zimbabwe", value: "000000000000000000000000000071" }, display_key: "MIDDLE_EAST", state: "E", text: "MIDDLE_EAST", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/MIDDLE_EAST" }, display_key: "WORLD", state: "E", text: "WORLD", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/0HIER_NODE/WORLD" }, "36": { "0": { value: "Loading" }, display_key: "REST_H", state: "C", text: "Not Assigned Country (s)", value: "HIERARCHY_NODE/1HIER_REST/REST_H" }, value: "root" } };

document.body.appendChild(getList(data.root));
```

Comment: one suggestion: `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v.text || v.value));` ... and one question ... why the `!v` in `if (!v || ....)`? `v` would never be falsey, would it?

Comment: `v` could be `null` and this is an object.

Comment: nevermind, I think I get it now why you'd have `!v`

Comment: Thank you so much this solves my purpose. But will this work for any json with a similar nested JSON structure right?

Comment: @Amit, it should if you hand over a structure like `data.root` and a `text` property. the last could be guarded by a custom callback.